# How to return virtual attribute in Rails depending on session/cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I have a model Book. It has properties - name, author, price.
Also, I have currency switcher on the site. I want to format price depending on currency, selected by the user.
Ruby has number_to_currency function, but it is not that I want, because I need special formatting of the price (for russian we have: 1 рубль, 2 рубля, 5 рублей).
So, I made the virtual attribute price_formatted.

```
def price_formatted
  case cookie[:currency]
  when 'usd'
    '<span>$'+price.to_s+'</span>'
  when 'eur'
    '<span>&euro;'+price.to_s+'</span>'
  else
    '<span>'+price.to_s+'</span> '+Russian.p(price, 'рубля', 'рублей', 'рублей')
  end
end
```

Russian.p makes russian pluralization for numbers. The error is that in price_formatted function cookie is not defined.

P.S. If there is another "right" way to make this thing work - please, teach me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass cookie[:currency] value as a parameter to this helper method.

It makes much more sense, actually: helper methods shouldn't know anything about user cookie, try to keep them as pure as possible!

EDIT: oh, is it a model method? You call it *virtual attribute*, so I assume so. You should convert it to a view helper then. It makes no sense to have **presentational** logic inside the model class. Create book_helper.rb under helpers folder, and put that method inside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new in Rails. So, I have many of this "simple" problems.

Comment: Sure! Just feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining a virtual attribute in the model, i prefer to use the decorator pattern which control how an attribute is going to be display in the view. You can take a look at this gem https://github.com/drapergem/draper. Inside draper, you can access cookie, session and so on.

Comment: Yes, decorator is a good idea also, but maybe that's an overkill to what author wanted to achieve.